# Laravel with method takes a lot of time for M:N relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I've got three tables: **attendees, attendee_tag and tags**, M:N relationship between attendees–tags. The table attendee_tag holds additional column named value. Now consider 800 attendees, 140 tags and 36 000 entries in attendee_tag table (one attendee usually doesn't have relation with all tags).

I want to get fe. 500 attendees with their tags and values. So I wrote this Laravel method:

```
$attendees = Attendee::where('event_id', '=', $event_id)
    ->with(['tags' => function($q) {
        $q->select('tags.id', 'value_type');
    }])
    ->paginate($pagination);
```

This produces following sql queries

```
"log": [
    {
      "query": "select count(*) as aggregate from `attendees` where `event_id` = ?",
      "bindings": [
        "2"
      ],
      "time": 1.31
    },
    {
      "query": "select * from `attendees` where `event_id` = ? limit 500 offset 0",
      "bindings": [
        "2"
      ],
      "time": 40.99
    },
    {
      "query": "select `tags`.`id`, `value_type`, `attendee_tag`.`attendee_id` as `pivot_attendee_id`, `attendee_tag`.`tag_id` as `pivot_tag_id`, `attendee_tag`.`value_string` as `pivot_value_string`, `attendee_tag`.`value_int` as `pivot_value_int` from `tags` inner join `attendee_tag` on `tags`.`id` = `attendee_tag`.`tag_id` where `attendee_tag`.`attendee_id` in (...)",
      "bindings": [
        ...
      ],
      "time": 721.62
    }
  ]
```

If I'll run these queries directly in database, they're fast enough, but when I made an api call, I'm waiting for the result 28 seconds ... why is it so slow? Can I somehow improve it?

Comment: Do those tables have indexes on the columns you're querying?

Comment: Is the query also fast enough when you have 500 elements in the `attendee_id in (...)` part of the query? My experience is that queries slows down a lot when adding many elements to in(), and that changing to using a sub-query speeds it up a lot. 
Not sure how to make that work with paginate in Laravel. I would probably have ended up with using a raw sub-query in the with part or concatenated the results from tags, but I am known for writing huge scary queries to save some trips to the DB

Comment: yes ... and again, database queries are really fast: last one tooks 0.0174 seconds, if I run it directly ... with 500 attendee_ids inside in() ... and returns 24717 rows

Comment: Did you remember to run ´FLUSH TABLES´ before you tested the query in the database, to know that the result is not from cache?

Comment: @rypskar of course

Comment: OK, never know what is tested with questions asked here. If the log is from Laravel, do you get any listings in the slow-query log in MySQL? Trying to find if it is the db or Laravel that is the bottleneck. It might be that it is Laravel that is the problem when it builds objects based on the result from the db

Comment: @rypskar here you can find log of one api call to retrieve 500 attendees and their tags with values: https://pastebin.com/nr1ciMKs, postman time: 27202 ms  ... Am I right, that database worked on it ~24 second because of time `Close stmt` and `Quit`?

Comment: hm, probably not, I run the latest, most difficult query from terminal and got 24649 rows in set (0.05 sec) (after flush tables) ... so the problem is – PHP is slow (or Laravel?)

Comment: You have more than 24k rows, and Laravel is building objects with the result. So lots of work to do. Maybe using chunking will help https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent or maybe you could use raw PDO. You could also get a smaller resultset by concatenating the tags instead of having each as it own row, if that don't break your api